# How To format group expression result In reportviewer?

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010

I have an application in which I will have to format the results
of the summation of the values in a column in a database table that are presented in a reportviewer. The issue is that the values are not formatted with thousand separators.

The code I use to achieve the sum grouping is:

```
Sum(Fields!rate.Value)
```

and the output i want to achieve is this:

```
1,234,567.00
```

Instead of

```
1234567
```

How can I make this value have a thousand separator with commas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a numeric type, you can use [The numeric `"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) with a culture has `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) and `,` as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for example [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
var i = 1234567;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

prints

```
1,234,567.00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/2V0Ksu)</kbd>.

Comment: I have a reportviewer,inside which i have grouped some rows on the value of a particular column.For me to get the format,i need to add an expression to the textbox that contains the value of the sum...and the accepted way is ...similar to this "=String.Format("{0:0,0}")..."....so how can i incorporate your function into this?...Thanks

Comment: @ewom2468 Your `Fields!rate.Value` isn't that already `1234567`? It isn't a numeric value? If it is not, have you ever try to parse it to `int` first? By the way, numeric values doesn't have _any_ format. Their string representations might have a format.

Comment: No......the values  are dynamic and are based on the the content in the columns in the database table.They are  grouped in rows...and the sum is in a row added below the group ....and displayed in the reportviewer.There are many rows and groupings in the report

Comment: @ewom2468 Values can be dynamic but isn't `1234567` a numeric value? What is the type of that `Sum` returns? Is it a string? Is it an int? I can't say clearly understand your problem based on your comments. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: The datatype of the value in the database (sqlservercompact) is "money"...so i am just summing up the "money" values..."1234567"...was just an illustration

Comment: @ewom2468 Why do you save them as a `money` type? Why don't you keep them as a numeric value?